# How I can move contact from one list to another using PHP API

Tags: constants, constantcontact

I am using PHP SDK for constant contact plugin. I want to move contact from one list to another. I have tried following code it will generate BAD response error.

```
$action = "Updating Contact";
$contact = $response->results[0];
foreach ($contact->lists as $key => $value) {
   unset($contact->lists[$key]);
}
$cc->contactService->updateContact(WPYog_ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact,true);
$contact->addList((string)$_POST['list_id']);
$contact->first_name = 'Sudhir';
$contact->status = 'ACTIVE';
$contact->email_addresses[0]->status = 'ACTIVE';
$contact->last_name = 'Pandey';
try {
   $cc->contactService->updateContact(WPYog_ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact,true);
}catch (CtctException $ex) {
   var_dump($ex->getErrors());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer. First of all fetch the record by using this

```
 $action = "Updating Contact";
 $contact = $response->results[0];

 // Now empty the list
 $contact->lists = array();
 $contact->addList((string)$_POST['list_id']);
 $contact->first_name = 'Sudhir';
 $contact->status = 'ACTIVE';
 $contact->email_addresses[0]->status = 'ACTIVE';
 $contact->last_name = 'Pandey';
 try {
    $cc->contactService->updateContact(WPYog_ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact,true);
 }catch (CtctException $ex) {
   var_dump($ex->getErrors());
 }
```